# detach an SQL server from visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

I'm pretty new to developing in Visual studio and working on databases.

I am working on a program that deals with reading and writing data to a database that I created with Visual studio.

I need to work on this project from another computer and copying over the project files was a breeze but I'm facing issues when it came to copying the `.mdf` database file.

Upon research it seems like, at least in the Microsoft SQL Server program, that I would have to "Detach" the database before copying it over to a different computer. So I am assuming I would have to do something similar with my Visual Studio Database as well.

Anyone has any inputs with regards to this?

If there is not much that I can do, I guess I could recreate all my tables and everything in Microsoft SQL Server program, so that it would be easier to move the database if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not so clear to me. Do you want to detach the database in visual studio? Simply right click on the database in the Server Explorer and select Detach.

Comment: I am a little confused here, when you say visual studio database are you referring to the sql database?

Comment: No you don't want to detach the database and then move the files over. You should create a database backup and then restore that backup on another sql server.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want all the computers running your app to access a central / common data store then you need to create your database only once on a Sql Server that is available to everyone. You then have a common connection string to that server and the database it is hosting for your app. The result in this scenario is no copy or backups/restores are necessary.

Comment: If every PC has their own local copy of the data then the best solution is to work with [Sql Express LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx). It allows for dynamically pointing to a local db file which can be copied when you deploy your app.

Comment: I think it's fine to detach and attach a database in your scenario, what I would do though is copy the mdf and ldf files across, instead of moving or cutting. If there is an issue, you still have the original files for re-attaching the database.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation such as yourself when I began developing my first core application. You have a few different options including:

- Detach an already created database from the hosted SQL Server service and "re-attach" to another SQL Server service that is accessible from the desired set of hosts. You have to essentially disconnect the database from the service before you are able to transfer or migrate it since the process will have an exclusive lock on the .mdf file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx
- Create the necessary .sql scripts to construct the database and run in the appropriate order e.g. create database, create tables, etc. to re-construct the database at the service location.The neat thing about this technique is if you have already created the database (which  it sounds like you have) SQL Server allows you to generate scripts rather than having to write them yourself. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx
- Finally you may use a subscription based service such as SQL Server through Azure to host the service for controlled global access aka DBaaS (Database as a Service). I can't post anymore links, but look at **Microsoft's Azure SQL Server hosting service** if you are curious about this option.

The unfortunate part you have to decide is how much time you would like to invest in this. I began developing the application from scratch which led me to developing scripts to conjure up the database for deployment purposes. Good luck!